# sectionNameKeyPath with custom CoreData model

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am working on an app, where I want to display a UITableView filled with student projects. Each project entity has several attributes like title, description, etc. and is also linked with relationships to other entities like students, study course and so on.
What I am trying to do now, is, to use the study courses as sections in which are all the respective projects which are made by students from that study course.

So far, my code looks like this

```
    - (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Project" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"title" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[sortDescriptor];

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController =
        [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
            managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext
            sectionNameKeyPath:Nil
            cacheName:Nil];
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

and this is a screenshot of the CoreData model[image: CoreData screenshot].

I am really new to Obj-C and haven't designed the data model myself, so I'm kind of lost here and would be really glad about any help.

Comment: I'm not a master at Core Data, but the sectionNameKeyPath: would be an attribute (or relationship) of Project and each section would be one study course. It looks likes you have a relationship called "projectToStudyCourse" so you might be able to set the sectionKeyPath: to @"projecttostudycourse.title" where title is the name of the attribute for the title of the study course. And of course set the section header to the study course title. Also, you would need to change the sortDescriptor to @"projecttostudycourse.title".

Answer (score 0):

You haven't asked a specific question yet, but I can give you some basic direction. The way you're creating your `NSFetchedResultsController` looks correct except that you need to do two more things: sort the result by course title and set the `sectionNameKeyPath` to course title (I'm assuming your `Studycourse` entity has a `title` property, but substitute another property as needed).

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    ...

    NSSortDescriptor *courseTitleSortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"projecttostudycourse.title" ascending:YES];
    NSSortDescriptor *titleSortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"title" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[courseTitleSortDescriptor, titleSortDescriptor];

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController =
    [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                        managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext
                                          sectionNameKeyPath:@"projecttostudycourse.title"
                                                   cacheName:Nil];

    ...
}
```

Note that by providing two sort descriptors, the projects will first be organized by course and then, within each corse, by project title. The other thing worth noting is that key paths use dot notation to follow entity relationships. So the way to reach the course title from a project entity is `@"projecttostudycourse.title"`.

Comment: Thank you so much! This helps already a lot.
Now I am just getting some strange behaviour which I cannot explain.
I have one exemplary project which appears in every section and some projects are repeating and others not showing at all:
[Simulator screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gjyy9jlhu3gcai3/Screenshot%202013-11-13%2020.55.09.png)

Comment: Would need to your updated code as well as `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and your `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` methods (unless you've copied them exactly from Apple's documentation). Can you update your question?